# Android ImageView is not bring to front

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview, xml-layout

android ImageView is not bringing to front in RelativeLayout

Tried to call bringtofront() didn't work
tried setting visibility to true didn't work

**XML CODE**

```
           <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <!-- This file is /res/layout/main.xml -->
         <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:id="@+id/spellingLevel1Layout"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         android:orientation="horizontal" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/canvas_container"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/magnetboard" >

       <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="480dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="600dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true" />

     </RelativeLayout>

   </LinearLayout>
```

**Java Code**

```
   public class spellingLevel1 extends Activity {         
   rel1 = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.canvas_container);
   mImageView1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
   image1();

}
  public void randomNumber() {
      Random rando = new Random();
      currentLetter = myImageList[rando.nextInt(myImageList.length)];
  }
  public void image1(){
      //randomNumber();

      mImageView1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
      mImageView1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.spelling_);        
      mImageView1.bringToFront();
      mImageView1.requestLayout();




  }
```

**UPDATED CODE**

```
   rel1 = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.canvas_container);
   mImageView1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
   image1();

}
  public void randomNumber() {
      Random rando = new Random();
      currentLetter = myImageList[rando.nextInt(myImageList.length)];
  }
  public void image1(){
      //randomNumber();

      mImageView1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
      mImageView1.setImageResource(R.drawable.spelling_); //updated here to setImageResource          
      mImageView1.bringToFront();
```

Still does not show

its not the full code but it should be everything to help you see what is included in here

Comment: where's the rest of your layout file?

Comment: sorry the imageview is inside the relative layout

Comment: do you need the whole xml layout?

Comment: It would be nice to know what else is in the layout - such as if you have a SurfaceView or a VideoView - something that does not conform to standard z-orders.

Comment: I updated it theres really nothing in here, just a standard relative view

Comment: You shouldn't need to call `bringToFront()` or `requestLayout()`. What happens if you remove those lines?

Comment: nothing its like its not there

Comment: i think the problem is not with the order of the views. try to change the background of the image to white and set it's size to 50*50 to see if it's visible. i think the problem is with your resource or the location of the image (maybe the screen is smaller than 480*600?)

Comment: Decrease the margins?

Comment: decreasing the margins worked, but question, will this margin it out for every device or am I only setting these margins for my device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define the image source of the `ImageView`.
because it's size is set to `wrap_content` and it has no content, the size stays 0.

Comment: This seems a little misleading. The width attribute stays at `wrap_content` - so once content is added (aka the image source), the width will no longer be zero. Lookup `LayoutParams` for a better understanding.

Comment: That's right, but he never set the content so it stays on 0 :).

Comment: He should change the setBackgroundImage to setImageResource

Comment: I have an array of images that's why it's set background image.  How would I convert the image resource to accept an array form

Comment: the same way you do this now, just change the setBackgroundImage to setImageResource. I'm not sure I understand the problem

Comment: I think I may be confused because I am a novice.  Basically when I try calling imageresource it gives me an error

Comment: now what happens is the imageview is not bringing to the front of the drawable relative background